# Slick Slider from KenWheeler

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, slider

i have implemented the Slick Slider in a homepage of a Rails 4 app and have this bug:

The slider works fine on opening the page but if i come back to homepage after navigation it doesn't work and all the images are displayed on the page. When i refresh the page the slider works just fine..

i have defined the root path to be:

```
  root "pages#index"
```

The jquery to call the slick slider is in the app.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        fade: true,
        speed: 900,
        autoplaySpeed: 1000,
        dots: true
    });
});
```

link tags in the head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/slick-theme.css"/>
```

and Scripts at the end of the body in the main layout:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Any idea of where this bug can be?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this,
 $('.slider').not('.slick-initialized').slick(sliderFunction);

or

Try to use setTimeout function and reinit slick slider.

Thank you